# How to terminate / stop a for loop

Tags: python, loops, survey, terminate

I am making a survey in Spyder. I need to make it so the output does not allow for anyone under 18 to complete the survey.... I can get it to print the error message but the survey still continues...

As you can probably tell, I am a beginner.

```
excluded_ages= '17''16''15''14''13''12''11''10''9''8''7''6''5''4''3''2''1''0'
age_input=input('Enter your age: ') 
print(input)
if age_input in excluded_ages:
    print('You may not proceed with this survey')
    break

postcode_input=input('Enter your postcode: ')
print(input)
```

I don't even know if break is the right function here, either way, it is showing up as an error because it is outside the loop... everything I type is either outside the loop or outside a function!

Comment: You did not show any loop at all, so without a [mre] it's hard to tell where you have to place anything.

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: what were you expecting this `excluded_ages= '17''16''15''14''13''12''11''10''9''8''7''6''5''4''3''2''1''0'` to do?

Comment: Try removing the `break`. You don't seem to need it there.

Comment: @SiHa I didn't know how else to list the ages that I want excluded... this list does work and if I type in '12' for example, it produces the error message but then goes on to ask 'Enter your postcode'

Comment: @quamrana without the 'break' or without anything there, it goes on to ask 'What is your postcode', which I do not want if the person is under 18!

Comment: @jps perhaps I dont quite understand what a loop is pahaha

Comment: But you didn't mention the Postcode bit in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have since added the remainder of the existing code!

Comment: Ok, so what do you want the code to do  when the age is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First there is no loop to `break` from so the `break` statement does nothing. Let me suggest a way to simplify this. My example will simply exit the program.

```py
import sys

age = int(input('Enter your age: '))
if age < 18:
    print('You may not proceed with this survey')
    sys.exit()
```

without using packages you can do this:

```py
age = int((input('Enter your age: '))
if age < 18:
    print('You may not proceed with this survey')
else:
    print('Starting survey...')
    # survey code here
```

Comment: I have tried this and it produces 'AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'exit'...

Comment: I think having an else would be better here instead of using `sys.exit()`. OP did mention they were new to programming and might not fully understanding if statements yet nor loops.

Comment: @goose.mp4 I agree with you however i answered with `sys.exit()` as I believed this to be the program flow that the OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: I have been told that we are not meant to be using python packages... does this mean I should not be using import sys...?

Answer (score 0):

Break is used to forcefully exit a loop, but an `if` statement is not a loop, which is why you're getting that error. Just put the rest of your survey code in an else statement:

```
if age_input in excluded_ages:
    print('You may not proceed with this survey')
else:
    print('Continuing survey')
    ...
```